# Macro to cut and paste certain percent of rows in same sheet

Tags: vba, xls

I am trying to create a macro which does a row count, cut and paste the top 10% and bottom 10% rows (of the total count) to a different column in the same sheet. Please help me with the macro.

**Edit**:

So far I have tried the below code:

```
Sub top10() 
Dim i As Variant 
Dim p As Integer 
Dim pp As Long 
Dim endrow As Long 
endrow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
pp = Round(endrow * 90 / 100, [1]) 
p = Round(endrow * 10 / 100, [1]) 
For i = 1 To p Range("A" & i).Select Selection.Cut Range("E" & i).Select ActiveSheet.Paste Next 
End Sub
```

The problem with the above code is: takes too long if I have approx 10k rows. Is there a better way, I could implement to run faster

Comment: try to add your current macro (something you already tried yourself) to get help

Comment: I am new to macro's, so still trying one.

Comment: Ok, So far I have tried the below code:
Sub top10()    
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim pp As Long
    
    Dim endrow As Long
    endrow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    pp = Round(endrow * 90 / 100, [1])
    p = Round(endrow * 10 / 100, [1])
    
    For i = 1 To p
    Range("A" & i).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("E" & i).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste    
    Next
    
End Sub

The problem with the above code is: takes too long if I have approx 10k rows. Is there a better way, I could implement to run faster.